# Stablish uni-directional SFP network link

Tags: networking, ethernet, optical-media

I am trying to establish a uni-directional Ethernet link where a singular fiber is used to transmit data to the receiver. The Rx of the transmit side and the Tx of the receive side are not physically connected, like in a Data diode scenario. The problem is, as soon as I detach the tx line from one side, both side link status goes DOWN. can anyone give advice to overcome this problem? do I need to change the Linux SFP driver to mask link status as always UP?

Comment: I wonder if that depends on the hardware on either end, or autonegotiation settings

Comment: Suppose you _do_ get this working fine for a week or two. And then a hurricane blows into town, and the bits stop flowing. First thing a maintenance tech is going to ask: "Put it in Remote Loop for me, please."